# PHP While and ForEach not producing desired results

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I am currently using a `while` statement to get each of the associated records for a `meal_id` but my `foreach` is not working as desired. My goal is to produce the meal row for each meal found, then display the meal items associated with that meal below it, then loop through to the next meal and repeat.

Currently, the result is showing the correct meal, but then displaying every meal item for every other meal below it. Such as:

```
Meal
Meal Item
Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
Unrelated Meal Item
```

When it should be doing:

```
Meal 1
Meal Item
Meal Item

Meal 2
Meal Item

Meal 3
Meal Item
Meal Item
Meal Item
Meal Item
```

I would like to also obtain the number of items in that meal also, and display that in the meal row of the table.
Here is my code so far and any help you can provide would be amazing! :-)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($DBServer,$DBUser,$DBPass,$DBName);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    $view = 'empty';
if(isset($_GET["v"]))
    $view = $_GET["v"];

switch($view)
{
    default:
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Today (default view)";
        break;
    case 'all':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "All Records";
        break;
    case 'today':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Today";
        break;
    case 'yesterday':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Yesterday";
        break;
    case 'week':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE meal_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Last 7 Days";
        break;
    case "fortnight":
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE meal_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Last 14 Days";
        break;
} ?><br>

<div class="viewdesc">Current View: <strong><?php echo($viewstatus); ?></strong></div><br>
<br>
<?php 

    // Start record fail error checking

    if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
    // Start record fail error checking */

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {?>
          <div id="resultserror">
No results could found for the selected view.</div>
          <?php } else { ?>
              <table id="results" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th align="center">Meal #</th>
<th align="center">User #</th>
<th align="center">Meal Items</th>
<th align="center">Meal Date</th>
<th align="center">Meal Time</th>
<th align="center">Meal Notes</th>
</tr>
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    ?>
<tr>

<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_id']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['user_id']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo("Items: " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . "");?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['meal_date'])));?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['meal_time'])));?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_notes']);?></td>

</tr>
<?php foreach ($result as $row)
{?>
<tr>
<td align='center' colspan='4'><?php echo($row['meal_item_name']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_item_measure']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_item_measurement']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="8" align="center">- end of report -</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
                     }?>
```

Comment: I suggest not using the `JOIN` and instead doing a 2nd set of queries (one for each meal, getting specifically that meals items) inside the loop. Doing this with a JOIN results in you getting [numer of items in that meal] rows for each meal each containing the meal. You'd need to restructure / take care of that when looping in your case, which you don't have to when using the extra-query-route.

Comment: How does that fair on the performance side of things though with thousands of users with hundreds of meals each with their own thousands of meal items? Won’t querying the different tables back and forth come down to over processing?

Comment: Depends on your indexes, modern DBMS are handling that without any fuss.

Comment: Okay, shall give it a whirl! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refractored your code a bit to use 2 queries instead of a `JOIN`.

Note that I'm not a fan of interweaving HTML and PHP tags like this - but that's probably personal preference and not the topic of this question:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($DBServer,$DBUser,$DBPass,$DBName);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$view = 'empty';
if(isset($_GET["v"]))
    $view = $_GET["v"];

switch($view)
{
    case 'all':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "All Records";
        break;
    case 'today':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Today";
        break;
    case 'yesterday':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Yesterday";
        break;
    case 'week':
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals WHERE meal_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Last 7 Days";
        break;
    case "fortnight":
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals WHERE meal_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Last 14 Days";
        break;
    default:
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals WHERE DATE(meal_date) = CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");
        $viewstatus = "Today (default view)";
        break;
}

if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

$meals = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $meal = array(
        "meal_id" => $row["meal_id"],
        "user_id" => $row["user_id"],
        "items" => array(),             // Gets filled next
        "date" => date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['meal_date'])),
        "time" => date("g:i A", strtotime($row['meal_time'])),
        "notes" => $row['meal_notes']
    );

    $itemResult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblmealitems WHERE meal_id = ".$row["meal_id"]);
    while($itemRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemResult))
    {
        $meal["items"][] = array(
            "meal_item_name" => $itemRow["meal_item_name"],
            "meal_item_measure" => $itemRow["meal_item_measure"],
            "meal_item_measurement" => $itemRow["meal_item_measurement"],
        );
    }

    // Add it to the meals list
    $meals[] = $meal;
}

?>
<div class="viewdesc">Current View: <strong><?php echo($viewstatus); ?></strong></div><br>
<br>
<?php 
    if (count($meals) === 0) {?>
        <div id="resultserror">
            No results could found for the selected view.
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <table id="results" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Meal #</th>
                <th align="center">User #</th>
                <th align="center">Meal Items</th>
                <th align="center">Meal Date</th>
                <th align="center">Meal Time</th>
                <th align="center">Meal Notes</th>
            </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($meals as $meal)
        {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td align='center'><?php echo($meal['meal_id']);?></td>
                <td align='center'><?php echo($meal['user_id']);?></td>
                <td align='center'><?php echo("Items: " . count($meal['items']) . "");?></td>
                <td align='center'><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($meal['meal_date'])));?></td>
                <td align='center'><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($meal['meal_time'])));?></td>
                <td align='center'><?php echo($meal['meal_notes']);?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($meal["items"] as $mealItem)
            {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' colspan='4'><?php echo($mealItem['meal_item_name']);?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo($mealItem['meal_item_measure']);?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo($mealItem['meal_item_measurement']);?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="8" align="center">- end of report -</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<?php
    mysqli_close($con);
}?>
```

Comment: Hm.. Couldn't you (minimally) at least suggest OP should set the `$query` string in each case, and run a `mysli_query( $query );` at the _end_ of the switch?

Comment: That worked amazing @cckep though I needed to modify a few things, such as the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` statement where it needed to be changed to `   $meal = array(  "meal_id" => $row["meal_id"], "user_id" => $row["user_id"], "items" => array()` and 
`"meal_date" => $row['meal_date'], "meal_time" => $row['meal_time'], "meal_notes" => $row['meal_notes']);`

Comment: Out of curiousity, is it difficult to add 2 parts of the array together to display the total meal weight (by adding each of the `meal_item_measure` so if it was 600grams and 300 grams it would display in the meal header as 900 grams (I get that there would be formulations involved to process the varients of grams, kg, pounds, etc, but more as to calling reference not just to the count of the items in the list, but to the math of the counted items array value.

Comment: @cale_b I already thought I went a bit further than needed to answer this question (although I must admit I actually thought about doing exactly that when moving parts of OPs code... though I didn't want to change too much so that the OP still recognizes his code and sees the relevant parts I changed) - feel free to edit the answer (or provide your own) if you feel the need though ;-)

Comment: @cloudseeker You could do anything you want inside those loops. Just create an overall "meal weight" and add the individual items weights (converting them to a common unit before) inside the inner loop.

Comment: @ccKep Thank you. Will keep that in mind for a mod when I have more time. I really appreciate all your help.